# Сохранение и загрузка массива Дат

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, дата, datetime

Как правильно осуществлять сохранение и загрузку массива дат DateTime?  Сейчас я осуществляю сохранение массива вот так. Правильно ли я делаю или есть вариант оптимальней?

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public DateTime[] times = new DateTime[100];

    private void Awake()
    {


            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Time" + i))
                {
                    times[i] = DateTime.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Time" + i));
                }                    
            }    
    }

#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR                               
    private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
    {
        if (pause)
       {                
          for (int i= 0; i<100; i++)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Time"+i, times[i].ToString());
        }
       }  
    }

#else
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        for (int i= 0; i<100; i++)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Time"+i, times[i].ToString());
        }

    }
#endif 
}
```

Comment: `PlayerPrefs` - худший способ хранить что угодно, кроме каких-нибудь настроек.

Comment: Сохраняй в json формате в файл

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Почему вы так считаете?

Comment: @Andrew, потому что на win этот "файл" хранится вообще говоря в реестре, который не предполагает хранение **не** метаданных. Более того, на разных платформах есть ограничения по объему записи. Да и скорость чтения из `PlayerPrefs` крайне мала по сравнению с каким-нибудь своим json'ом.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Спасибо за объяснение.